# sending data from form to form

Tags: php, forms, email

i have php application, there is 2 form, in first form user input data (his email, phone number etc)
second form is on second page that can be opened only of user inputed data correctly in first form
second form wait for users input and then send post request to sendemail.php (file with PhpMailer code that send message using email)

there is first form on first page

```
        </form>

        <?
        /*
        $random = rand(1, 9);
        $all = $data_s["RAW"]["" . $obmen['valute'] . ""]["" . $exc['valute'] . ""]["PRICE"];
        $pro = '0.' . $random . '';
        $x = $all - ($all * ($pro / 100));
        */
        
        
        
$random = rand(0, 0);
$all = $data_s["RAW"]["" . $px1['valute'] . ""]["" . $px2['valute'] . ""]["PRICE"];
$pro = '0.' . $random . '';
$x = $all - ($all * ($pro / 100));
        ?>

<style>
.pull-right{float:right!important;
   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:0;
   text-align:right;
   border-left:0
}


</style>
        <?
        echo '<form method="post" id="exc-form" action="/?id=' . $action . $ob1 . '&exc=' . $ob2 . '">';
        ?>

        <div class="exchange-amounts">
            <div class="col">

                <br />
<?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Отдаете' : 'To pay')?> 

<?
//if ($ob2 != '58'){
?>

<span class="pull-right"><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Получаете' : 'You receive')?></span>
<?
//}
?>

<br/>
<input class="box" type="text" maxlength="18" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="<?= $id['name'] ?>" name="sum1" id="amount1" value="<?= ($_SESSION['suma_num1'] != null ? ''.$_SESSION['suma_num1'].'' : '')?>">


<?
//if ($ob2 != '58'){
?>
<input data-walet="<?= $exc['short_validator'] ?>" class="box" type="text" maxlength="18" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="<?=($ob2 == '58' ? 'Euro' : ''.$exc['name'].'')?>" name="sum2" id="amount2" value="<?= ($_SESSION['suma_num2'] != null ? ''.$_SESSION['suma_num2'].'' : '')?>">
<?
//}
?>

            </div>
        </div>

<?
if ($ob2 == '58'){
?>

<br/>
<input class="box" type="text" style="font-size: 12px;" placeholder="SEPA euro account IBAN" value="" name="num_sepa">
<input class="box" type="text" style="font-size: 12px;" placeholder="Full name" value="" name="name_sepa">
<br/>

<?
} else {
?>
<br/>
<font color="orange"><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Назначение' : 'Purpose')?></font>
<input class="box2 buy_seller" type="text" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="<?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Ваш' : 'Your')?> <?=$exc['name']?> <?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? ''.($px2['valute'] == 'RUB' ? 'номер карты' : 'адрес').'' : 'address')?>" value="" name="card">
<br/>
<?
}
?>


<?
if ($ob2 == '58' || $ob2 == '59'){
?>

<br/>
<font color="green">Reference (if needed)</font>
<input class="box2" type="text" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="Reference (if needed)" value="" name="reference">
<br/>

<?
}
?>







<?
if (!isset($user['id'])) {
?>
<?php
            if ($_SESSION['email'] != null){
            $email = check($_POST['email']);
            }

            if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $sql->esc($_POST['email']);
            $email = check($_POST['email']);
            $text = 'Здравствуйте! Вы создали заявку на обмен по направлению: &laquo;'.sum($exc['sum1']).' '.$cou['valute'].'&raquo; &rarr; &laquo;'.sum($exc['sum2']).' '.$obmen['valute'].'&raquo; и подписались на Уведомления о статусе заказа!';
            $result = $mailSMTP->send($email, 'Новый обмен', ''.$text.'', $from);
            }
?>
<br/>
<font color="orangered"><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Номер телефона' : 'Phone number')?></font>
<input class="box2 phone_mob" type="text" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="telephone number" value="" name="phone">
<br/>
<?
}
?>
<!--
<input id="notice_email_input" required="" type="text" name="email" value="" data-label="Email" data-error-empty="Это обязательное поле" data-error-invalid="Введенный адрес не является Email адресом">
-->
<br/>
<font color="orangered"><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'E-mail' : 'E-mail')?></font>
<input class="box2" id="email-input" type="text" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="E-mail" value="" name="email"><?=$_SESSION['email']?>
<br/>





<br/><input type="checkbox" name="save" value="1"/> <?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Я согласен с' : 'I agree with')?> <a href="/politika-aml/"><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'AML/CTF и KYC Политикой' : 'AML/CTF and KYC Policy')?></a><br/>

        <br />

        <div class="exchange-wrapflex">
            <div class="exchange-button center">
                <button name="btn_exc" type="submit" class="exchange-submit disabled" id='submit-btn_exc'><span><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'Начать обмен' : 'Start exchange')?></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        localStorage.setItem('email', email);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sendemail.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                // Action on success
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // Action on error
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

second form on second page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'sendemail.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function(){
        alert("Email sent successfully!");
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<form>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i want to make second form automatic, it must use email from first form and make auto sumbit, send post request to sendemail.php with email fild like now, but automaticly without userinput

if someone can help me i will be extremly grateful

Comment: Just make the PHP code which handles the first form submission send the email directly. No need for two pages or two forms, or any AJAX code. I said the same thing the [last time you asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77822290/sending-messanges-and-trying-to-save-old-functionality-of-function), but you didn't respond.

Comment: P.S. Your code is badly formatted and hard to read. Try making it clearer to understand.

Comment: Maybe i can just add all that functionality to first form? and then delete second, but when i tried to do this my first form was broken

Comment: Well that's a good approach, but maybe you did some small thing wrong. So instead of asking us to start again, you should show us what you tried, and explain exactly what error or unexpected result occurred when you ran the code. "Broken" isn't a useful description of the problem, we can't help with that unless you provide specific details.

Comment: i changed script and first form string, after that it could only make sending emails, i dont know how to combine sending emails and functionality to create new transaction (when it was just form for creating transaction it has no <script>)

Comment: Don't waste time _describing_ what you did, just [edit] your question and show us exactly.

Comment: Also read that [Short Tags Are Deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags) --  If this is a profession, please take some courses.  I haven't seen code this badly formatted in a long time.  I haven't seen so many bad practices in a long time.

Comment: `i dont know how to combine sending emails and functionality to create new transaction`...just make the code do one task, and then make it do the next task, on the next lines. If you put code for different tasks into separate functions, it becomes easier to understand and manage the different bits of the code, too. Without seeing exactly what you tried, it's very hard to understand where you are having trouble, so please provide that code.

Comment: I thought about implementation of it, now it can send emails succesfully if i will create variable like

$_SESSION['email'] = "myemail@gmail.com";
but i dont have ideas how to make autocreating that variable after input data to that input string 

<font color="orangered"><?=($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru' ? 'E-mail' : 'E-mail')?></font>
<input class="box2" id="email-input" type="text" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '' ?>" name="email">

if someone know, thanks a lot for help, and thanks for everyone for help!

Comment: You don't need that second input. Take the email address from the first form, and when that form is submitted, send the email then, immediately. No need for Session variables.